# Large background images using css

Tags: css

How can I load images to cover the whole background like some websites, using CSS.  Not  the usual background-image property but I want to load the images quickly.

#### Examples:

http://www.marinayachting.it/

http://alexandraowen.co.nz/

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: The image is a small pattern or is it a large image? (p.e. 1024x768)

Comment: assuming it fits on a slightly bigger than 1024x768
example could be bing, which has high-resolution images.

Comment: If you inspect the CSS on bing.com with firebug you'll see that it uses `background-image`. Check the div with `id="bgDiv"`.

Comment: if you have photoshop, make sure you use the "save for web" option to compress the file down to a reasonable size

Comment: Are you referring to how the image loads differently for CSS backgrounds vs. img tags? I've noticed that in some browser versions, while img tags show the image being loaded as it loads, row by row, css backgrounds are only displayed, all at once, once the image is finished loading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`background-image` is the only way to place images in CSS. If you want it to be vary large put it on the `body` element or a container `div` that fills the entire viewport.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('my_big_image.jpg') norepeat;
}
```

If you use a container `div` you can set `position:fixed; top:0; left:0` and the image will remain stationary when the page scrolls.

There's no magic to it. As far as getting it to load quickly I don't think there's much you can do if it doesn't repeat. If it does repeat then make sure your image is the size of one module. This can be as little as one pixel tall or wide depending on the content.

Comment: @jean your comment doesn't make sense. use a CDN, a faster server, or shrink your filesize. those are pretty much your only options.

Comment: did you even attempt to look at the source for that site? it's not even using css for that image. it's using an `<img />` tag. it's not doing anything special. the image size is 119.08KB

Answer (score 7):

There is no magic to making a background image load quickly, you just:

- Have a fast server.
- Compress the image as much as possible.
- Make your page HTML small so that the rest can start loading as soon as possible.
- Don't have many other images that also has to load.
- Don't have a lot of scripts and other external files that has to load.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't say what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found this tutorial helpful. ->

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

Bing is loading a normal background image with a fixed size. It´s not particularly fast (for me...), but perhaps it seems fast because the image is cached after the first time you load it.

Comment: What´s with the downvotes for almost all answers? An explanation would be nice...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style inline so that the image can start downloading without waiting for any css file to be ready.

Comment: can the guru who downvoted give me a reason why? Or you don't know what you're doing, just having too much free time...

Answer (score 0):

If you set an image let's say a picture as a background you need to make it large enough to accommodate large screen sizes. You don't want the experience on your site to be, that your picture repeats multiple times on the screen. Probably at the least width should be 1260px. If background is just a simple gradient, you can cut a small part of it in photoshop and apply it on the body like this:

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:#fff url(your/image/location.jpg) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
}

This method could be applied to divs too, Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example site, alexandraowen.co.nz, if you took a second to look at the JS they use, you would have seen the following:

```
// backgrounds --------------------------------------------------------------//

var Backgrounds = {};

Backgrounds.init = function()
{

    $('body').each
    (  
        function()
        {
            var imgsrc = $(this).css('background-image');
            if(imgsrc != 'none')
            {
                imgsrc = imgsrc.slice( imgsrc.indexOf('(') + 1 , -1);
                $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
                $(this).prepend('');
                if($.browser.msie)
                {
                    // ie 7 is the slow kid and we have to strip out quote marks ffs!
                    $(this).find('div.bg img').attr('src', imgsrc.split('"').join(''));
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).find('div.bg img').attr('src', imgsrc);
                }
            }
        }
    );
    Backgrounds.resizeHandler();
    $(window).resize(Backgrounds.resizeHandler);
    $('div.bg img').load(Backgrounds.resizeHandler);
}

Backgrounds.resizeHandler = function()
{   
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();

    $('div.bg img').each
    (  
        function()
        {   
            var wr = w / $(this).width();
            var hr = h / $(this).height();
            var r = Math.max(wr, hr);
            var imgw = Math.round($(this).width() * r);
            var imgh = Math.round($(this).height() * r);

            $(this).width( imgw );
            $(this).height(  imgh );

            var l = Math.round((w/2) - (imgw/2));
            $(this).css('margin-left', l+'px');
        }
    );
}
```

As well as the HTML on the page:

```
<body style="background-image: none; ">
```

If you dig into their scripts a bit more, you can see what they did. But I guarantee you it's nothing faster than just setting the `background-image` property.

Comment: i'm sure everyone here appreciates your thoughtless downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

`<img id="foo" src="bar" alt="">` with `#foo { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`
(use `position: absolute;` / `position: relative;` & `z-index` for layering as desired)

[Here's an old example](http://reisio.com/temp/stretch/).